# How to delete the lines from a file that do not contain dot?

Tags: command-line, text-processing

I have a file that contains data including urls. But there are various lines which are not urls. How can I remove them using Ubuntu terminal commands?

Here is the Sample file for reference: [Sample Data](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BzQ6rtO2VN95TWZ2dlBFZzRrS1U/view)

```
com.blendtuts/S
°=
com.blengineering.www/:http
±=
```

I want to have the output :

```
com.blendtuts/S
com.blengineering.www/:http
```

The extra unwanted lines do not have any dot. Hence, I want to remove the lines without dots

Answer (score 33, accepted):

One way with `sed`

```
sed '/\./!d' file
```

- `/\./` match literal dot (escaped with `\` because otherwise`.` matches any character)
- `!d` delete everything except the matched pattern

If you want to edit the file in place, add `-i` to the command after testing. (You can also add `.bak` to the `-i` flag `sed -i.bak ...` to create a local backup of the file.)

```
sed -i '/\./!d' file
```

Answer (score 26):

You could grep everything with a dot into a new file:

```
grep "\."  file > newfile
```

That way you can save your old file.

Answer (score 10):

Or keep the lines which contain a *dot*,

```
sed -ni.bak '/\./p' infile
```

Answer (score 8):

I think `awk` is that last one missing to the party:

```
$ awk -F\. 'NF>1' file
com.blendtuts/S
com.blengineering.www/:http
```

This sets the field separator to the dot. Then, it is a matter of printing those lines that have at least two fields: this will mean that at least one dot occurs.

Comment: A simpler awk solution would be to do it in the same vein as grep: `awk '/\./' file` -- that is, to print only the lines containing the character '.'.

Comment: @ChrisMidgley good one! Since this is what the answer with `grep` already suggested, I preferred to go with some `awk`-specific stuff :)

Answer (score 6):

Using perl:

```
perl -i -ne 'print if /\./' /path/to/file
```

Answer (score 6):

You can do this pretty easily with vim. If you are comfortable using vim as a text editor (opening, editing, and writing files), then do this:

```
:g!/\./d
```

If you are not comfortable using vim, or you would rather use it as a command-line tool, you may simply do from the terminal:

```
vim file -c "g!/\./d" -c "wq"
```

You could slightly modify this to save to a new file:

```
vim file -c "g!/\./d" -c "w newfile" -c "q!"
```

This uses vim's "global" command, which applies an ex command to every line matching (or not matching) a regex. In this case, the command is "(d)elete", and it will be applied to every command not matching the regex `\.`